# estoy realizando una creacion de tablas en SQL y a la hora de ejecutar, me aparece un error "Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE doctor_schedule (
 doctor_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 attention_time_slot_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 available tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 date date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (doctor_id,attention_time_slot_id,date),
 FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES doctor (id),
 FOREIGN KEY (attention_time_slot_id) REFERENCES attention_time_slot (id)
)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!
 Deberias mostrar las tablas relacionadas a ver si hay algun problema con ellas. Este create es correcto sintactimante.

Comment: agrega todas las tablas involucradas en la creación de dichas llaves foráneas

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberia ser de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE doctor_schedule (
 doctor_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 attention_time_slot_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 available tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 date date NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_doc_schedule PRIMARY KEY (doctor_id,attention_time_slot_id,date),
 CONSTRAINT fk_ds_doctor FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES doctor (id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_ds_attention FOREIGN KEY (attention_time_slot_id) REFERENCES attention_time_slot (id)
)
```

Ten en cuenta que los tipos de las claves foraneas deben ser del mismo tipo y mismo nombre.

Comment: la pregunta esta incompleta pues no muestra la estructura delas tablas restantes sería ideal esperar a que el OP agregue lo faltante necesario